# Is the "Face on Mars" an artificial structure?

Tags: aliens, mars, optical-illusions, archaeology

Is the famous image of a face on Mars a trick of the light or an artificial structure reprinting a face?

[image: Face on Mars]

Comment: Unfortunately not. When you look at even the original pictures in 3D it's clearly a rock.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, it's just a myth. That picture had a low resolution and a particular light angle made it look like a face, but see this:

[image]

Here's what it looks like from the oblique:
[image: 'face' on mars]

It's clearly not a face.

> What the picture actually shows is the Martian equivalent of a butte or mesa -- landforms common around the American West. "It reminds me most of Middle Butte in the Snake River Plain of Idaho," says Garvin. "That's a lava dome that takes the form of an isolated mesa about the same height as the Face on Mars."

--[source](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast24may_1/)

Comment: No face, but look at those roads!

Answer (score 28):

[The Face on Mars and Pareidolia](http://therelativelyinterestingblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/face-on-mars-and-pareidolia.html)

We have a habit of finding patterns were there are none (**Pareidolia**):

[image]

> ... with our knowledge of pareidolia, and
>   the high resolution images provided by
>   NASA, do you think the Face is still a
>   face, or an optical illusion enhanced
>   by the fact that we were originally
>   looking at very low resolution images?

[The Badlands Guardian](http://atlasobscura.com/place/the-badlands-guardian) in Alberta, Canada, discovered through "Google Earth".

[image]

Comment: I didn't see a face in that lamp...

Comment: @fredley: in case you're being serious, the lamp isn't a face. Pareidolia isn't just for faces, it's about "seeing" anything in a picture other than what the picture is showing. The lamp is slightly more rude example - clue: legs.

Comment: Actually, it's not a lamp. http://ebaumsworld.com/pictures/view/1042108

Comment: I see an artificial structure in the "Badlands Guardian"

Comment: @Nick T: the earphone (or oil well and track, to be more precise) were there before the aerial photograph

Comment: funny thing, if you add those to google's picasa it will probably pick all of them as a face and ask you to name them.